# How do I see processes from all users in SSMS2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I only see my own connections/processes in the new activity monitor... whereas in the earlier versions of SSMS you could see everyone's.  Do I need to change a setting or something?

Comment: What permissions / roles do you have on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to view the Activity Monitor in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008.

Under the processes make sure you have select Login as (All) to show all the processes.

By the way, do you see any of the system processes?